# Caps Lock button's green light not working after Mojave update

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, caps-lock

I've updated to macOS Mojave from High Sierra recently. Since the update, the green light in <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> button is no more working.

The button is working, but the green light is not.

MacBook Pro, 15-inch, 2017 model.

Is there any solution how can I fix this issue?

Comment: What model is your machine?

Comment: MacBook Pro 15 inch, 2017 model

Comment: did you reset your SMC and NVRAM ?

Comment: no. didn't take any step, just restarted after the auto install was finished

Comment: Please use @ and first two letters of the name so I will get informed about your message

Comment: @Buscar웃 How can I reset SMC and NVRAM

Comment: for NVRAM https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: for SMC https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295  SMC can be tricky to do, so watch the MagSafe plug light briefly changing color so you know yo did it right.

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks. Problem solved after the NVRAM reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest your reset your NVRAM, following the procedure from Apple.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Answer (score 4):

If you are running Karabiner that could be the issue.  Try updating Karabiner and this should solve your problem.
Should that not help, check your version of Office...sounds crazy but when I updated from 2016 to 2019 quite a few bugs 'magically' disappeared.